# How to read randomly different GetElementById elements from 1 javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

The following two lines are stored in de file testjava.js

```
document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML = "Some content is here.";
document.getElementById("content2").innerHTML = "Some other content here.";
```

This is in the body of my HTML.

```
<span id="content1">GetElementById</span>
<span id="content2">GetElementById</span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="testjava.js"></script>
```

It works perfect.
Even the following works perfect. The first element is read, but not the second.

```
<span id="content1">GetElementById</span>
<!-- <span id="content2">GetElementById</span> -->
```

But when I just want to read the second element (and not the first), it does not work.

```
<!-- <span id="content1">GetElementById</span> -->
<span id="content2">GetElementById</span>
```

In other words how do I write an external javascript file from which I can read multiple (or one) elements, independent from the order of the elements in the javascript file and independent from the number of elements stored in the javascript file.

Comment: check the dev tools. You probably have errors suggesting that you cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("content1")` is `null` if the element doesn't exist, and `null` doesn't have a `innerHTML` property. You can check if the element exists before setting the `innerHTML` property:

```
const $content1 = document.getElementById("content1");
if ($content1) $content1.innerHTML = "Some content is here.";
const $content2 = document.getElementById("content2");
if ($content2) $content2.innerHTML = "Some other content here.";
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.